# selective deletions from list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"b","x","d"},{"a","z","b"},{"a","x","b"},{"a","x","c"},{"b","z","d"}}
```

Certain consecutive elements of this list will have identical first and last members (in this example, `"a"` and `"b"` in `lis[[2]]` and `lis[[3]]`) and I would like to delete the element that has "x" as its middle element, to give:

```
res = {{"b","x","d"},{"a","z","b"},{"a","x","c"},{"b","z","d"}}
```

It seems like a job for SequenceCases, but am having no luck.

Comment: elements 1 and 5 also have identical first and last members...Shouldn't you erase the first element, too?

Comment: Take a look at `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.

Comment: Another approach could be to start with `Split[lis, #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] && #1[[3]] == #2[[3]] &]` to group the consecutive elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {OrderlessPatternSequence[{a_, "x", c_}, {a_, b_, c_}]} :> {a, b, c}]
```

> {{"b", "x", "d"}, {"a", "z", "b"}, {"a", "x", "c"}, {"b", "z", "d"}}

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to look at the differences between adjacent elements, find those which equal {0,0,x_}, and remove them from the list.

```
lis[[Complement[Range[Length[lis]],Flatten@Position[Differences[lis], {0, 0, x_}]]]]

{{"b", "x", "d"}, {"a", "z", "b"}, {"a", "x", "c"}, {"b", "z", "d"}}
```